Propensity score weighting with post-treatment variables
It's been emphasized to balance pre-treatment variables when doing propensity score weighting (PSW) as balancing post-treatment variables can introduce bias.
I want to ask your insights on the case where we have no pre-treatment variables. The settings are:

We do not aim to estimate causal effect of treatment. Rather, we aim to minimize or reduce imbalance between different treatment and control groups.
In our case, the "treatment" occurred during childhood period while our samples are adults. Hence, we have no pre-treatment variables except age.
Specifically, we are planning to use generalized boosted model (GBM) for estimating propensity scores for multinomial treatment, developed by Greg Ridgeway.

We found no significant difference between the estimates from naive unweighted model and PSW model.
I wonder if we can still utilize PSW with post-treatment covariates as we found no evidence for significant post-treatment bias here. Additionally, as you may guess, in our data setting we cannot opt for other methods, such as IV or DID.

There are many, many reasons for not using propensity scores, detailed here.

To generate balancing weights to balance covariates between treatment groups, you can indeed include post-treatment variables as predictors in the propensity score model, but only if those variables are not descendants of the treatment. This means you can add variables that occur after the treatment in time, such as prognostic factors, but not variables that are causally affected by the treatment. For example, consider the following causal graph representing the causal relationships between treatment $A$, outcome $Y$, pre-treatment covariates $W$, post-treatment prognostic factors $X$, and descendants of treatment $Z$:
$$
A \leftarrow W \rightarrow Y  \quad\text{ and }\quad Z\boldsymbol{\leftarrow} A\rightarrow Y\leftarrow X
$$
In this scenario, you can use pre-treatment covariates $W$ and post-treatment prognostic factors $X$ as predictors in the propensity score model, but not post-treatment variables $Z$ because they are directly influenced by the treatment ($Z\boldsymbol{\leftarrow} A$). Including $Z$ would introduce (post-treatment) selection bias, rendering any direct comparison between treatment groups devoid of causal interpretation.

This is so insightful and helpful. Thanks so much!
